# change name of dynamically added select option element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am dynamically generating some dropdowns and then allowing them some of those to be removed on board dyanmically. so that time, i have encountered an error of selection option (dropdown) elements id mismatch. something like below is.

newly added dropdowns.

```
select name="CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][0]" id="client_time_window_0">/select>
select name="CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][1]" id="client_time_window_1">/select>
select name="CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][2]" id="client_time_window_2">/select>
select name="CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][3]" id="client_time_window_3">/select>
```

after i dynamically remove them via javascript. (lets say i am removing the second one) so then new ones will be displayed as followings,

```
select name="CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][0]" id="client_time_window_0">/select>
    select name="CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][2]" id="client_time_window_2">/select>
    select name="CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][3]" id="client_time_window_3">/select>
```

So now the issue i have is,  the names of the dropdowns are like this, **(0,2,3)**

```
CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][0], 
CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][2], 
CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][3]
```

So this is causing an error for me and i need to reorder this name and make it be like this, **(0,1,2)**

```
CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][0]
CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][1]
CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][2]
```

how can i simply rename these dropdowns name attribute (from 0 to how much ever dropdows are exisiting) ? appreciate an early reply

**EDIT 1**

I tried this, but didnt work.

```
$('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates select').each(function(i){
$(this).attr('name',"CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][i]");
});
```

Comment: Ensure that `id` attributes are unique on a Web page. "The objective of this technique is to avoid key errors that are known to cause problems for assistive technologies [...]". From this [article](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H93.html) at W3C.org

Comment: @Lan tnx and updated the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply reset the values using `.attr()` method:

```
$('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates select').attr('name', function(i) {
   return 'CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr]['+ i +']';
});
```

Comment: Simple things are better.

Comment: @undefined can you check my below answer and tell which is better performance wise ?

Comment: @mazraara Sure, by using `.attr()` method you don't have to create many unnecessary jQuery objects, using `.attr()`'s callback function is more efficient. You could also use `this.name = ... `  in the `.each()` callback, which is better than creating objects.

Answer (score 1):

I did this,

```
$('#tbl_dynamic_call_dates select').each(function(i){
 $(this).attr('name',"CSSAtapsClient[client_time_window_arr][" + i + "]");
});
```